# poblemas con android studio y gradle offline : "No cached version of ... available for offline mode"

Tags: android-studio

necesito una ayudita aca. Estoy tratando de comenzar a trabajar con android studio 3.5 y gradle 5.4.1 (offline) y aunque le especifico la dirección local de este me lanza el siguiente error:

> "No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.4.1 available
>   for offline mode."

No pongo el código porque casi tengo que hacer una tesis para estructurar las lineas. Pero tiene la configuración estandar que define android studio cuando creamos una aplicación nueva.[image: Esta es la imagen del build.gradle]

Comment: lo que sucede es que no tienes las librerias necesarias para el proyecto, necesitas desactivar el modo offline para descargar esa librerias

Comment: Quiere decir que necesito mas que el sdk y el gradle descargado?

Comment: @yoandry debes desactivar el modo offline y descargar la información necesaria para que posteriormente puedas trabajar en modo oflline, agregué respuesta. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

**El problema es precisamente que estas trabajando "offline" pero en este caso no has descargado la información definida en el `build.gradle`**.

En español el problema indica:

> "No hay versión en caché de ... disponible para el modo fuera de
>   línea"

Para solucionar esto, desactiva la opción "Offline work", y con conexión a internet sincroniza tu proyecto con los archivos gradle.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez realizado esto ya puedes trabajar "offline" desactivado la opción.